# Strange warning with ld

Tags: c++, gcc, warnings, ld

I received this warning from `ld` whe I was buliding my program:

> ld: warning: direct access in global constructors keyed to `_ZN12_GLOBAL__N_143ensure_log_is_created_before_maing_l_filterEto` global weak symbol vtable for `cs::ObjectFactoryAliasInstantiation<cs::DefaultCommandDispatcher>` means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.

The code witch refer the error is this:

```
class ObjectFactory {
        public :
        ObjectFactory(const char *alias):sAlias(alias){};
        std::string sAlias;
        virtual void* createInstance() = 0;
    };

template <class T>
class ObjectFactoryAliasInstantiation : public ObjectFactory{
public:
    ObjectFactoryAliasInstantiation(const char *alias):ObjectFactory(alias){};
    void* createInstance() { return (void*)new T(&sAlias); };
};`
```

and this:

```
        /*
         Class for register the dispatcher for the command
         */
    class CommandDispatcherRegister {  
    public:
        CommandDispatcherRegister(ObjectFactory *commandFactory);
    };

    /*
     Macro for help the Command Dispatcher classes registration
     */
#define REGISTER_AND_DEFINE_COMMAND_DISPATCHER_CLASS(CMD_CLASS_NAME)  class CMD_CLASS_NAME;\
static const CommandDispatcherRegister CMD_CLASS_NAME ## CommandDispatcherRegister(new ObjectFactoryAliasInstantiation<CMD_CLASS_NAME>(#CMD_CLASS_NAME));\
class CMD_CLASS_NAME : public CommandDispatcher\
```

end this:

```
 REGISTER_AND_DEFINE_COMMAND_DISPATCHER_CLASS(DefaultCommandDispatcher) {
        bool deinitialized;
```

Comment: Have you checked the things the linker suggested to you?

Comment: yes but i don't know what to check....

Comment: And `This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings` is not hinting to what to check?

Comment: the first thing i have  i had think was the #pragma GCC visibility but i don't have this.

Comment: What's this `ensure_log_is_created_before_maing_l_filter`?

Comment: @ClaudioBisegni: And thats the only way to influence visibility?

Comment: templates result in weak symbols as well I believe

Comment: not also the public, protected and private on class derivation syntax

Comment: public/protected/private doesn't influence weakness of symbols, just accessibilty at compile time

Comment: right, and what else influence the weakness of symbols?

Comment: Can you show any of the code for  `ensure_log_is_created_before_maing_l_filter` or `cs::ObjectFactoryAliasInstantiation`?

Comment: @ClaudioBisegni, basically just templates and explicit annotations, really

Comment: What version of g++ and ld are you using?

Comment: i edited the part of code that are implied

Comment: gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)

Comment: hmm, gcc-llvm? interesting. Try compiling this on the same settings, see if it gives the same warning: http://codepad.org/AlYrfxuN If it does, please post the assembly code output (ie, build with `-S -o test.s`, plus any other flags you pass to the main compile, and post the contents of `test.s`)

Comment: i added the comment on http://codepad.org/AlYrfxuN

Comment: @ClaudioBisegni, C++ code must be built using `g++`, not `gcc`

Comment: rigth, the compilation has been successful

Comment: @ClaudioBisegni, are you building your main program as a shared library?

Comment: i build a static library that contain the code showed upper. Then i compiled a main with that library. anyway i try to compile the code on linux machine with gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50) and i get no warning with the same scons script

Answer (score -2):

This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.

i.e. you changed some headers and didn't do a *full* re-build of your whole project. Do that now.

Comment: i used also scons to be my project(i work with Xcode but distribute it with scons) and i receive this warning also if i run scons -c and then scones. Anyway i'll try again

Comment: that's not the warning you'd get from changing a header but from compiling targets with non-matching -fvisibility settings. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9954259/48125