# iOS: C++ warnings in compiler after updating to Xcode 8.3

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, compiler-warnings

I updated to Xcode 8.3 last week. I cannot seem to get rid of this compiler warning:

`ld: warning: direct access in function 'std::__1::basic_filebuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::open(char const*, unsigned int)' from file '/Path/To/Derived/Data/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp/Build/Intermediates/myapp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/myapp_lto.o' to global weak symbol 'std::__1::basic_filebuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::open(char const*, unsigned int)' from file '/Path/To/Derived/Data/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp/Build/Intermediates/myapp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/myapp_lto.o' means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.`

What I've tried to resolve this warning:

1. Changing `Symbols Hidden by Default` to YES - in all targets
2. Changing `Symbols Hidden by Default` to NO - in all targets
3. Essentially everything [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920891/std-linker-error-with-apple-llvm-4-1) (though not fully related)
4. Cleaning/Deleting derived data/etc
5. Added `-fvisibility=hidden` to my target, as well as all cocoapod targets. ([described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894961/strange-warnings-from-the-linker-ld))

Any insight is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

*UPDATE 2017-04-10:*

This appears to be an issue generated by NewRelicAgent. Removing the cocoapod from my project eliminates the warning. Looking into this further.

Comment: might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894961/strange-warnings-from-the-linker-ld

Comment: Thanks, @NathanOliver I actually saw this post as well. I've gone through every target (including the cocoapod targets), and added `-fvisibility=hidden` to other c++ linker flags. This warning still persists.

Answer (score 2):

Response from New Relic support:

> We reviewed these warning messages with our Mobile Engineering team. They advised these warnings are related to a difference introduced in Xcode 8.3 - which isn't applied to the latest version of the New Relic iOS Agent built in Xcode 8.2.
>
> They also stressed that these warnings don't appear to have any negative effects - but please let us know if you notice any other issues.
>
> It's likely this issue will be resolved in the next release of the agent, when it will be built with Xcode 8.3.